# Disable cache-busting content hashes on quasar build

Tags: vue.js, webpack, quasar-framework, quasar

I would like to disable cache-busting hot loading content hashes on quasar build or even better i would like to set up my own re-naming conventions.

I can do this in Vue but the same strategy does not seem to work on Quasar and no documents seem to exist in regards to this.

Currently I have tried to set in quasar.conf.js:
filenameHashing: false

```
module.exports = configure(function(ctx) {
  return {
    // https://quasar.dev/quasar-cli/supporting-ts
    supportTS: {
      tsCheckerConfig: {
        eslint: {
          enabled: true,
          files: './src/**/*.{ts,tsx,js,jsx,vue}'
        }
      },
      build: {
        // Do not change the JS / CSS for hot loading.
        filenameHashing: false
      }
    },
```